# Error load data local CSV to BigQuery using Python

Tags: python, csv, google-bigquery

I'm new into data engineering field, and want to create table and inserting the data to BigQuery using Python, but in the process I got error message
[image]
even though I already set the google_application_credential through the shell, the error message still appear

here is my code

```
from google.cloud import bigquery  
from google.cloud import language
from google.oauth2 import service_account

import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL"]=r"C:/Users/Pamungkas/Downloads/testing-353407-a3c774efeb5a.json"

client = bigquery.Client() 

table_id="testing-353407.testing_field.sales"
file_path=r"C:\Users\Pamungkas\Downloads\sales.csv"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV, skip_leading_rows=1, autodetect=True,
        write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE  #added to have truncate and insert load
)

with open(file_path, "rb") as source_file:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_id, job_config=job_config)
    
job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print(
    "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
        table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
    )
)
```

Comment: s is missing at the end

Comment: which one? can you pointing out? @p13rr0m

Comment: You have GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL, but it is GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @p13rr0m suggested, you should have to use the environment variable as `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` instead of `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL` to resolve your issue.